# Low Voltage wiring and Rough-In Inspection

Tags: electrical

Does anyone have experience, guidance, tips on what is required for LV wiring at rough-in inspection?

I have run a number of speaker wires, coax, ethernet (CL2/CL3) but they do not all terminate in a LV Box rather I just have them dangling. This is because some wires will support in-wall speakers, in-ceiling speakers which I want installed in the middle of the studs and I have an idea on the height but will sort this out later at installation. So my thought was to leave them dangling to be covered by the drywall.

Same goes with my COAX subwoofer locations. I have them dangling in the wall and plan is to use a LV old work bracket post-drywall.

Thank you.

Comment: Inspectors are generally uninterested in LV wiring. Electrically, keep LV separate from AC power. Mechanically, observe manufacturer's specs for holes in structural members.

Comment: Helpful tip: take photos of all wiring, plumbing, and other utilities before sheetrocking. You'll thank me later.

Comment: The only thing I have seen inspectors check is the insulation on speaker wire, the cheaper clear insulation is not listed for use in the walls but is fine out in the open. Other than that they don’t look unless the LV / shares a box with power, there needs to be a divider in the box. Separate locations and listed speaker wire you should be golden.

Comment: Thank you and great tip Phil!